# MySql select all but data associated with specific value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table and I want to select all (via php query) but only the rows that matches course1, I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$comments = array();
$result = mysql_query("select * from comments where course1='$post_id' order by id ASC");
```

what's the right query?

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-------------------------+---------------+-------------
| id | post_id   | name     | url | email              | body               | dt         |
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-------------------------+---------------+-------------
|  1 | course2   | john     |     | john@john.com      | comments by john   | 2012-11-16 |
|  2 | course1   | wiki     |     | wiki@wiki.com      | comments by wiki   | 2012-11-16 |
|  3 | course2   | daniel   |     | daniel@gmail.com   | comments by daniel | 2012-11-16 |
|  4 | course2   | ram      |     | ram@ram.com        | comments by ram    | 2012-11-16 |
|  5 | course1   | velu     |     | velu@velu.com      | comments by velu   | 2012-11-16 |
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-------------------------+---------------+-------------
```

Comment: isn't the right way:

    $result = mysql_query("select * from comments where post_id = course1 order by id ASC"); 
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='course1' order by id ASC

I think you'd muddled your column names and search values in your sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the field name you're searching on:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from comments where post_id='$post_id' order by id ASC");
```

Where your $post_id string variable contains value "course1".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from comments where post_id='$post_id' order by id ASC");
```